# Could you please confirm or deny two identities involving weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind?

Tags: co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities, stirling-numbers

In the paper [1] below, among other things, Carlitz introduced weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind $R(n,k,r)$. He also proved that the numbers $R(n,k,r)$ can be generated by
\begin{equation*}%\label{S(n,k,x)-dfn}
\frac{(\textrm{e}^z-1)^k}{k!}\textrm{e}^{\lambda z}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty R(n,k,\lambda)\frac{z^n}{n!}
\end{equation*}
and can be explicitly expressed by
\begin{equation*}%\label{S(n,k,x)-satisfy-eq}
R(n,k,r)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}(r+j)^n
\end{equation*}
for $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\ge k\ge0$.
Specially, when $\lambda=0$, the quantity $R(n,k,0)$ becomes the Stirling numbers of the second kind $S(n,k)$.

I guess that the identities
\begin{equation}\label{QGWSID1}\tag{SID1}
\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j} \frac{R\bigl(2m+j-1,j,-\frac{j}2\bigr)}{\binom{2m+j-1}{j}}=0, \quad k,m\in\mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{QGWSID2}\tag{SID2}
\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j} \frac{R\bigl(2m+j,j,-\frac{j}2\bigr)}{\binom{2m+j}{j}}=0, \quad k>m\ge1
\end{equation}
should be valid.

Stronger but simpler than \eqref{QGWSID1}, the identity
\begin{equation}\label{QGWSID3}\tag{SID3}
R\biggl(2m+j-1,j,-\frac{j}2\biggr)
=\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\sum_{\ell=0}^j(-1)^{\ell}\binom{j}{\ell}\biggl(\ell-\frac{j}{2}\biggr)^{2m+j-1}
=0
\end{equation}
for $k,m\in\mathbb{N}$ should be true.

These guesses \eqref{QGWSID1}, \eqref{QGWSID2}, and \eqref{QGWSID3} are related to series expansions at $x=0$ of the functions
$$
\biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\biggr)^r
\quad\text{and}\quad
\biggl(\frac{\sinh x}{x}\biggr)^r
$$
for real number $r\in\mathbb{R}$. For details, please read the arXiv preprint [2] below.

Could you please confirm or deny these identities \eqref{QGWSID1}, \eqref{QGWSID2}, and \eqref{QGWSID3} involving the weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind $R(n,k,r)$?

References

1. L. Carlitz, *Weighted Stirling numbers of the first and second kind, I*, Fibonacci Quart. **18** (1980), no. 2, 147--162.
2. Feng Qi, *Series expansions for any real powers of (hyperbolic) sine functions in terms of weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind*, arXiv (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612 or https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.

Comment: you will want to add some motivation (you "guessed" this ?), to promote a helpful response.

Comment: Yes, I guessed them without explicit and short motivation. The motivation is in my brain.

Comment: Using the software Mathematica, I numerically verified these two identities, so it is better to prove their validity mathematically or combinatorially.

Comment: In form, these two identities I guessed are beautiful, so it should be interesting to prove them.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The motivation you required is at arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612. For this, I edited my question again.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Please read the arXiv preprint carefully, word by word, formula by formula, then perhaps you would get all answers to what you asked here.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker If this refers to Remark 6 in the paper, the paper seems to say that these are conjectured, and the author is asking here if these guesses are correct.

Comment: @YemonChoi -- indeed, I will delete the mistaken comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R(n, k, -\tfrac k2)$ is just the central factorial number $T(n, k)$. (Given the definition of the central factorial numbers, it may be more natural to use them in your context than $R$).

Consider [A136630](https://oeis.org/A136630). We have $\operatorname{A136630}(n, k) = 2^{n-k} T(n,k)$ (this may be stated explicitly by Comtet, Riordan, or Charalambides; if not, it will follow from the egf) and the combinatorial interpretation that $\operatorname{A136630}(n, k)$ counts set partitions of $n$ elements into $k$ odd-sized blocks. This immediately gives (SID3), since an even-sized set cannot be partitioned into an odd number of odd-sized blocks, nor an odd-sized set partitioned into an even number of odd-sized blocks.

(SID2) is equivalent to the following theorem: if $1 \le m < k$ then $$\sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{k-j} \binom{2m+k}{2m+j} \operatorname{A136630}(2m+j, j) = 0$$

This theorem has a combinatorial proof: consider set partitions of $2m+k$ elements into $k$ odd-sized blocks where blocks of size $3$ or greater are coloured red and singleton blocks can be coloured red or blue. Then the sum counts such set partitions weighted by $(-1)^{\textrm{number of blue partitions}}$. ($j$ is the number of red partitions). Observe that partitions containing at least one singleton can be paired with the partition which differs only in the colour assigned to the singleton with the smallest element, so that the sum counts the number of partitions of $2m+k$ elements into $k$ odd-sized blocks of at least $3$ elements each. But if $k > m$ there are no such partitions, proving the theorem.

For the equivalence to (SID2) we rearrange $$\begin{eqnarray*}
\textrm{LHS} &=& \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} \frac{R\bigl(2m+j,j,-\frac{j}2\bigr)}{\binom{2m+j}{j}} \\
&=& \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^j \frac{k!(2m)!}{(k-j)! (2m+j)!} T(2m+j,j) \\
&=& \frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2m} \binom{2m+k}{k}} \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{k-j} \binom{2m+k}{2m+j} \operatorname{A136630}(2m+j, j) \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank Peter Taylor for your proof of the identity (SID3), and then (SID1), in my question. Could you please give another reference to the relation $R(n, k, r)=h_{n-k}(r, r+1, r+2, \dotsc, r+k)$ in your answer?

Comment: @qifeng618, only partially. If we have a triangle $T(n,k) = h_{n-k}(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{k+1})$ where $h_0(\vec{s}) = 1$ then it's easy to derive $T(n+1,k) = T(n,k-1) + s_{k+1} T(n,k)$ and conversely to show that this recurrence with base case $T(0,k) = [k=0]$ gives $h_{n-k}(\cdots)$. You may be able to find a reference for this in a textbook: I haven't looked. Then Carlitz, *Weighted Stirling numbers of the first and second kind, **II***, Fibonacci Quart. 18 (1980), no. 3, 242-257, eqn (1.4) as corrected reads $R(n+1,k,\lambda) = R(n,k-1,\lambda)+(k+\lambda)R(n,k,\lambda)$.

Comment: @qifeng618, I've found a reference. Andrei Z. Broder, [The r-Stirling numbers](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/82/949/CS-TR-82-949.pdf), Discrete Math. 49, 241-259 (1984). The correspondence between Broder's notation and Carlitz's is ${n \brace k}_r = R(n-r, k-r, r)$. Unless I've overlooked it, none of the identities in Broder's paper is immediately equivalent to SID2.

Comment: Thank Peter Taylor for your hard endeavor to find a reference. You are a real mathematician. How can I contact with you via e-mail? My e-mail address is qifeng618@......

Comment: I will throw out for anyone who's interested that I conjecture a stronger result than the theorem proved, namely replacing the binomial coefficient $\binom{2m+k}{2m+j}$ with $\binom{3m+1}{k-j}$. This would allow proving by induction that the same holds for $\binom{n}{k-j}$ if $3m+1 \le n \le 2m+k$. It may have a similar combinatorial proof, but I think it's likely to be somewhat less elegant.

Comment: @qifeng618, to confirm publicly what we've discussed privately, in my judgement this answer doesn't cross the threshold of a publishable unit, and since I therefore have no plans to publish it you may feel free to include the proofs in your monograph if you wish.

Comment: Dear Peter Taylor, do you mean that you have no intent to independently publish the answer of yours elsewhere and so anyone, including me, can include your proofs of your answer in some manuscript by me or others? In other words, do you mean that you permit me or others to recite your proofs of the above answer in some manuscript? Currently, I don't do so, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612v3. If I don't misunderstand you, I will include your proofs in some manuscript of mine.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Dear Peter, I included your proofs in my manuscript: Feng Qi and Peter Taylor, Several series expansions for real powers and several formulas for partial Bell polynomials of sinc and sinhc functions in terms of central factorial and Stirling numbers of second kind, arXiv (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612v4.